# Gradient Descent Update Rule

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, optimization, vector-analysis, machine-learning

I've written a function of my own, and I'm trying to optimize it with gradient descent, but I don't know how to update each variable, as one variable may control an angle, and another variable may control an area.

I've tried to optimize my parameters each step by:

vars = vars - (learning_rate * error * vars)

But it doesn't seems to work as magnitude of parameters may differ.
I've also tried:

vars = vars - (learning_rate * error *derivative_of_vars)

To what should I change my update rule? Should I take the derivative of the error function in relation to the derivative of every parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for:

`vars = vars - (learning_rate * gradient_of_error(vars))`

In the one-dimensional case, the gradient of the error function is its derivative.

[Source (wiki)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent)

Comment: thank you! In fact I had to take the partial derivative of every parameter in respect to the derivative of the error function as I was optimizing an equation which variables were codependent, but it now works. My takeaway was your hint about it being true in the one-dimensional case (most online examples)